# Raspberry Pi with wrong GPIO value in Codesys

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, codesys

I have a Codesys application which runs on my Raspberry Pi. On this Pi, there are two LED's and two buttons connected. The LED's are working fine as they are connected to a GPIO output pin. But the buttons don't work as expected. However it seems like the buttons are connected fine, Codesys gives not the result I want. On default the button is not pressed. However the Codesys application returns the TRUE value. Everytime I press the button, this boolean is changed to the FALSE value. This actually has to be the opposite. When pressing the button the value has to be TRUE. When released it has to be FALSE.

I may seems like the button has not been connected correctly. I double checked this and actually it seems connected good. And since the Codesys application does work properly using the button, the connection doesn't seems like to be the problem.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong? Can the boolean values be flipped in Codesys?

Comment: Can't you just do a `not` statement and then it works fine?

Comment: Why not using `gpio-keys` driver with respective DT excerpt and handle the events like any other input device (like regular keyboard)?